# I want to plot point shapefile on a raster to know if they are at the right place in R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, point

I have one raster and a shapefile of points. I want to check them if they are in the same coordinate system by plotting them together on a map (like in a classical GIS), here the R script :

```
# raster first
library(raster)
setwd("P:/folder/")
my.raster <- raster("raster_1991.img")

# shapefile second
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(maptools)

setwd("P:/folder")
meteo.shp <- readShapePoints("meteo.shp")

# set up same coordinate system
coord.sys <- CRS("+init=epsg:2065")
proj4string(meteo.shp) <- coord.sys
proj4string(my.raster) <- coord.sys

# plot them in one map (window)
plot(meteo.shp)
plot(my.raster, bg = "transparent", add = TRUE)
```

I am able to read the data and plot them, but only separately. How can I make sure myself that the points - meteo stations - are exactly where they should be if I cannot check them on a map?

Comment: What CRS information did the two inputs have before you assigned EPSG:2065? Did `proj4string()` throw any warnings when you used it?

Comment: @obrl_soil I don't know exactly, when I do `summary(meteo.shp)` before assigning EPSG I get `Object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame
Coordinates:
               min      max
coords.x1 20.06176 20.28333
coords.x2 49.11886 49.26306
Is projected: NA 
proj4string : [NA]`

Comment: Run `proj4string(meteo.shp)` and `proj4string(my.raster)` before setting them to coord.sys - do they both return NA?

Comment: @obrl_soil No, only the meteo.shp is NA.

Comment: Are you sure that it should be EPSG:2065? What made you pick that system?

Comment: @obrl_soil I wanted to have them in the same system used in my country.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `tmap` package, which can draw spatial objects on a web map with a choice of map layer backgrounds, such as OpenStreetMap.

There are other ways of doing that, including the `mapview` package and the `leaflet` package. There are also packages that will download OpenStreetMap tiles for context in R graphics plots but `tmap` and the web map will allow you convenient zoom and pan functionality.